# How have I misunderstood structural references?

Tags: excel

I have a table with travel expenses and I want to simply sum an entire column.

[image: Table of travel expenses]

What I came up with is the following:

```
=SUM(REPLACE(Table1[[#Data], [Main Currency]], 1, 4, ""))
```

But it seems to only work with the data that is on the same row as the formula. I thought it would sum the entire column. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Replace function works on a single string, not an array of strings. You may want to use a helper column in your data that turns the text into a number row by row, and then sum the helper column.

Or, you need to use an array formula, which is confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. In this case, it is not sufficient, though, since the array that is served to the Sum() function will consist of a list of text strings. Sum ignores text. Therefore, you will need to coerce the string to a number, like this:

```
=SUM(REPLACE(Table1[Main Currency],1,4,"")+0)
```

Remember to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to confirm the formula. Even this will give you an error if there is a blank cell in the column.

So, it might be easier to clean up the data before trying to sum it.

You may want to use Power Query to clean up the data before you let any formulas loose on it.

Comment: Or you could use `SUMPRODUCT` and avoid the `CSE`.  (I've never tested which is faster)